# Rest API alternative for SOAP Sabre Air Availability API

Tags: java, rest, soap, sabre

I want to know that is there any **REST API** alternative available for **Sabre** Soap "Air Availability API" which will basically serves all the purpose and have same refinement parameter? If Yes, provide me the disadvantages the alternative one has.

Answer (score 1):

According to this:

https://developer.sabre.com/product-catalog?f%5B0%5D=target_audience%3A4

There is no option for REST web service.

SOAP and REST are two ways to interoperate throw Web protocol, both have their pros an cons, none is better than other.

If you have a technical requirement that constraints you to REST, you can use an ESB like WSO2 to translate SOAP to REST.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Generate+REST+API+from+SOAP+Backend